# Flask Import errors when importing models on pythoneverywhere

Tags: flask, import, model, flask-migrate

Local everything works fine but when I go to pythoneverywhere I get error: **Cannot import name "User" from "Data.Domain.User"**, without Flask-Migrate db works just fine, also, I tried to copy the content of Data.Domain.User module to app.py and it works, the problem appears just when I want to move it on another folder ( location ).

This is what I have in app.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_script import Manager, Server
from flask_migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_mail import Mail, Message

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'blablablastrongsecretkey'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'connstring'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

migrate = Migrate(app, db)

manager = Manager(app)
manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)

login_manager = LoginManager(app)

from Data.Domain.User import User

from Presentation import App

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

Module Data.Domain.User is this:

```
from app import db, login_manager
from flask_login import UserMixin


@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))


class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    uuid = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(40), unique=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "User(\n\tID: " + str(self.uuid) + "\n\tUsername: " + self.username + "\n)"
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem renaming and moving the app.py file in another folder, and then I just imported app from it

```
from Presentation.Server import app
```

This is the import from Data.Domain.User file